# How to get SQL Query from provided date (start from 1 second after midnight) and to date (end at 1 second before midnight)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I want to update all the records updated between 14/05/2021 to 15/05/2021.

@from and @to is in dateTime format, UpdatedTime is also in datetime.

I am currently using like this

```
SELECT *
FROM tblUSER
WHERE UpdatedTime > @from and UpdatedTime < @to
```

I want "@from" to start from a second after midnight of the given date and "@to" to be until a second before midnight.

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Change `>` and `>=` and you're there. `UpdatedTime >= '20210514' AND UpdatedTime < '20210515'` would include *all* times on 14 May 2021.

Comment: UpdatedTime needed to be casted to the format that your variables are. else you will not be able to see the results.

Comment: Why 1 second after/before midnight? In SQL Server `datetime` has a resolution of approximately 3.333ms so if a row has an `UpdatedTime` of `2021-05-14T00:00:00.003` should it be ignored?

Comment: Midnight (00:00:00.000) is the **start** of any date, not then end of the previous date.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query. I declared @From and @To as variables. You can change according to your requirement.

```
 DECLARE @FROM AS DATETIME  = '2021-05-14 00:00:01.000' 
, @TO AS DATETIME  ='2021-05-14 23:59:59.000'

 SELECT * 
 FROM  tblUSER
 WHERE UpdatedTime BETWEEN  @FROM AND @TO
```

Answering your question in comment:

```
 DECLARE @FROM AS DATETIME  = '2021-05-14 00:00:01.000' 
 --User entered value is set to @To variable
 , @TO AS DATETIME  ='2021-05-14'

--Mofify the varaible to add 23 hours and 59 minutes. 
 SET @TO = DATEADD( MINUTE, 59,   DATEADD(HH,23, @TO) )
 -- Testng @To value
 SELECT @TO 

 --Selecting records between from and to values
 SELECT [Name], [UpdatedTime]
 FROM  tblUSER
 WHERE UpdatedTime  BETWEEN  @FROM AND @TO
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Hello, THanks for commenting. '@to' will be entered by the user. If the user enter '2021-15-14', sql will convert it to '2021-05-14 00:00:00.000'.

let's say the value for UpdatedTime for record "A" is '2021-05-15 12:10:00.000' So, in this context, this record A will not be returned by the query. I need to tweak is so that record A will be return. Regards,

Comment: Let me add it for you. @WymoOo

Comment: @WymoOo I posted the answer for you. Please have a look.  There are many other ways of doing this. I added one solution. Hope this will help you to get your solution. Happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your question is exactly.  But a better way to phrase the logic is:

```
where UpdatedTime >= '2021-05-14' and
      UpdatedTime < '2021-05-15'
```

This is no need to fiddle with seconds when what you care about is dates.  This `where` clause can easily be incorporated into an `update`.

Comment: This won't work because "@to" will become '2021-05-15 00:00:00.000". Let's say the value for UpdatedTime  for record "A" is '2021-05-15 12:10:00.000' 

So,  in this context, this record A will not be returned by the query. I need to tweak is so that record A will be return.

Regards,

Comment: @WymoOo . . . Your question specifically says "Let's say I want to update all the records updated between 14/05/2021 to 15/05/2021."  There is no time component.